# Page template gives 'Parse error: syntax error' when used, but no error found!

Tags: pages, templates, errors, parse

I get this message, whenever I activate this page template for one page, for instance about.php :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/u425744603/public_html/wp-content/themes/helle/page-notime.php on line 1

There is no error! This is actually the same template I've been using for a few weeks and it worked perfectly fine.

This is the code for the template:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Page Without Time */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="container">

    <div id="columns">
        <div class="col-9">

    <div id="content">
        <?php /* Top post navigation */ ?>
            <?php global $wp_query; $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages; if ( $total_pages > 1 ) { ?>
                <div id="nav-above" class="navigation">
                    <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link(__( '<span class="meta-nav">&laquo;</span> Older posts', 'your-theme' )) ?></div>
                    <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link(__( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&raquo;</span>', 'your-theme' )) ?></div>
                </div><!-- #nav-above -->
            <?php } ?>

        <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) {
                $post = $posts[0]; $c=0;
                while ( have_posts() ) {
                    the_post();

                $c++;

                if ( $c == count( $posts ) ) { ?>
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
                <div style="width: 100%; border:none;"></div>
                <?php
                }

                else { ?>
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
                <div style="width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid #000;"></div>

                <?php
                    }
                } // end while
            } // end if
        ?>

        <?php /* Bottom post navigation */ ?>
            <?php global $wp_query; $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages; if ( $total_pages > 1 ) { ?>
                <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
                    <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link(__( '<span class="meta-nav">&laquo;</span> Older posts', 'your-theme' )) ?></div>
                    <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link(__( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&raquo;</span>', 'your-theme' )) ?></div>
                </div><!-- #nav-below -->
            <?php } ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->

    </div>
        <div class="col-3 grey">
            <p>Hoi</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- #container -->

<div id="primary" class="widget-area">
</div><!-- #primary .widget-area -->

<div id="secondary" class="widget-area">
</div><!-- #secondary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I would really appreciate it if someone can tell me why I get this error in all of a sudden.

Comment: Maybe your FTP program has removed the line-breaks during upload? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163344/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-on-line-1

Comment: @toscho Thanks a lot! Do you know why FileZilla for instance removes line-breaks ?

Comment: @toscho place it as an answer so I can state it's solved

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do with it but I know that when you download from a Linux server FileZilla adds double line brakes unless download mode is set to binary. Maybe this is something similar?

Comment: no problem. My pleasure.

Comment: I am not even sure whether this is on-topic … :) You could solve your problem, that's all I need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Maybe your FTP program has removed line-brakes burring upload. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163344/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-on-line-1

toscho feel free to post your comment as an answer. I just thought I would do it so this thread could be marked as answered